# Mailcomposer with custom Navigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposer

i am facing a new problem.

I have custom navigation controller in my application. I have to add an image to navigationbar and i used this code in my AppDelegate-

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"top-red.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 44)];
}
@end.
```

This code is working fine for me, but when i use MFMailComposer in my application and call it on a button event i see that the navigationbar of MFMailcomposer is also changed to my custom navigationbar which i don't want to change.

Any Ideas!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a category to the UINavigationBar, you are adding a method to **all** instances of UINavigationBar.

Since you are overriding `drawRect:` that means that whenever **any** navigation bar wants to draw itself it is using your method rather than the standard `drawRect:`

Rather than do this, you should just add the image to your navigation bars where you want them , rather than change it globally as you have done here.

Comment: In this case i am facing another issue. I added image to UINavigation bar and I also added UINavigationBar buttons but after adding image buttons are not visible :(

Comment: Maybe the image is being drawn *above* the buttons, which is why they are not visible.

Comment: The sequence of adding navigation images and buttons is first i am adding image to navigation bar and then adding buttons to navigation bar. Please suggest how to solve this issue.